# Frontend application to be deployed on kubernetes with multiple environments . How to update Dockerfile with node and nginx for separate environments

Tags: node.js, docker, kubernetes, nginx

I have  a frontend application which I want to deploy using same image in my different kubernetes clusters for separate environments. My Dockerfile currently creates environment specific image which I cannot use in different environments. How to update the dockerfile / deployment yaml so that same image can be deployed.
Below is my dockerfile -

```
FROM node:16-alpine AS build
WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN npm install
# Set the environment variable
ARG NODE_ENV
ENV NODE_ENV=$NODE_ENV
# Choose npm script based on the environment
RUN npm run build-${NODE_ENV}

#RUN npm run build-dev
# Serve Application using Nginx Server
FROM nginx:alpine

RUN rm  -f /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html
COPY --from=build /app/dist/APP/ /usr/share/nginx/html/
EXPOSE 80
```

My code has folder src/environments/environment.dev.ts and src/environments/environment.qa.ts

```
import { IEnvironment } from '@models/environment.interface';
import { EnvironmentTypes } from '@enums/environment.enum';

export const environment: IEnvironment = {
  environmentName: EnvironmentTypes.DEV,
  isLocal: false,
  isProduction: false,
  apiBaseUrl: 'https://devurl/',
  imagePath: 'assets/images/',
  iconPath: 'assets/images/icons/',
  publicS3BucketUrl: 'https://devurl'
};
```

If I can update my dockerfile and can pass env variables in my deployment.yaml or any such approch.
I am aware about how to pass the env variables in deployment yaml but my question is how I can manage the npm build part as it is env specific. ie.  **npm run build-dev or npm run build-qa**

How to handle this ?

Comment: You can pass in all those values as environment variables as described in the kubernetes documentation, either [statically in an `env` section](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/#define-an-environment-variable-for-a-container) or by extracting them [from a configmap or secret](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#configure-all-key-value-pairs-in-a-configmap-as-container-environment-variables).

Comment: yes I am aware about how to pass the env variables in deployment yaml but my question is how I can manage the npm build part as it is env specific. ie.  npm run build-dev or npm run build-qa

Comment: Maybe `npm run $BUILD_ENVIRONMENT_NAME`, where `BUILD_ENVIRONMENT_NAME` is one of the environment variables you pass in your deployment manifest?